# Finding the latest status

Tags: mysql, query-performance, optimization, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables `events` and `event_status`.
The `event_status` table is the history table, and latest being the current one. The `events` and `event_status` have a one-to-many mapping.
I need a optimized query to find the event and its current status.

I am using MySQL btw.

Eg:
`events table`

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Event 1 |
| 2 | Event 2 |

`event_status`

| id | event_id | status | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | Proposal Accepted | 2023-01-10 13:40:01 |
| 2 | 1 | Planning | 2023-01-10 13:55:26 |
| 3 | 1 | Cancelled | 2023-02-05 09:00:00 |
| 4 | 2 | Started | 2023-02-05 09:00:00 |

Output I need>

| ID | NAME | STATUS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Event 1 | Cancelled |
| 2 | Event 2 | Started |

I looked into multiple ways to generate the data.
Some queries that I tried are:

1. Removing the old status using subquery in where

```sql
SELECT e.*, es.status
FROM events e
         JOIN
     event_status AS es
     ON e.id = es.event_id
         AND es.id = (SELECT id
                      FROM event_status es2
                      WHERE es2.event_id = e.id
                      ORDER BY es2.created_at DESC
                      LIMIT 1);
```

2. Finding the smaller status during join and filtering on where.

```sql
SELECT
    e.ID,
    e.NAME,
    es.status AS STATUS
FROM
    events e
JOIN
    event_status es ON e.ID = es.event_id
LEFT JOIN
    event_status es2 ON es.event_id = es2.event_id AND es.created_at < es2.created_at
WHERE
    es2.event_id IS NULL;
```

3. Getting max created_at for each event and adding extra join with normal join.

```sql
SELECT
    e.ID,
    e.NAME,
    MAX(es.status) AS STATUS
FROM
    events e
JOIN
    event_status es ON e.ID = es.event_id
JOIN (
    SELECT
        event_id,
        MAX(created_at) AS latest_created_at
    FROM
        event_status
    GROUP BY
        event_id
) AS latest_status ON es.event_id = latest_status.event_id AND es.created_at = latest_status.latest_created_at
GROUP BY
    e.ID, e.NAME;
```

4. Using window function to get the row id and selecting the top row

```sql
WITH Status_row_id AS (
    SELECT
        es.event_id,
        es.status,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY es.event_id ORDER BY es.created_at DESC) AS row_id
    FROM
        event_status es
)
SELECT
    e.ID,
    e.NAME,
    rs.status AS STATUS
FROM
    events e
JOIN
    Status_row_id rs ON e.ID = rs.event_id
WHERE
    rs.row_id = 1;
```

I need some help in choosing the best query, or strategies to make the qurey faster.

Comment: Have you tested using the explain plan ? Do you have indexes `(event_id ,created_at DESC)` in `event_status` table and `(ID)` on `events` table ? Which one the four queries is faster on your environment ?

Comment: I agree with @ErgestBasha - you need to test in your own environment. Off the top of my head, I would go with the window function - they were developed for this very task so I can only assume that there are optimisations in place (but this **is** MySQL).

Answer (score 0):

Groupwise-max is messy to query.  Let's revamp the system to make it simpler.

Let's change `events_table` to `events_current` and add columns for the *current* status of the event.

Anc change the name `events_status` to `event_history`, since it really has the "history", not the "current status".

`Current` would be updated (actually use IODKU, so that the same action can create a new event).  When adding a new row to `history` also update `current`.  Note that your specific request (in this Question) is easily handled via a `SELECT ... FROM current ...`.

`History` would be essentially as you have it now.  It is `INSERT`-only, there would be no `UPDATE`.  You would `SELECT` from it only if you needed "old" info that is not in `current`.

If you don't want to switch to that schema design, see the `[greatest-n-per-group]` tag or [*Groupwise-Max*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max)